# why Woocommerce Custom payment gateway ipn callback return -1 and cant handle?

Tags: php, woocommerce, plugins, payment-gateway, woocommerce-blocks

With my plugin I generate a payment link that redirects the customer to the corresponding bank, according to a documentation that I found and that matches the response
https://docs.shophumm.co.nz/custom_integration/checkout_api.html#response-postget

I have 3 url, x_url_callback, x_url_complete and x_url_failure included in the payment intent, once the payment is done I want to return to the ecommerce, but capturing the response, to know if the payment is canceled, complete, etc.
for this I have been advised to use woocommerce_wc_api with a function called check_ipn_response, but it doesn't work for me, I should change these x_urls but I don't know for which ones.

the url that appear is this: http://localhost:8000/?wc-api=WC_Plugin_Gateway?x_account_id=secret&x_amount=1230.0&x_currency=CLP&x_reference=57&x_result=failed&x_timestamp=2024-01-30T17:46:33Z&x_message=Cancelado%20por%20usuario&x_signature=secret

the docs in woocommerce forums recommend use ipn callback like this

```php
class WC_Plugin_Gateway extends \WC_Payment_Gateway{


public function __construct(){
         $this->notify_url = WC()->api_request_url('WC_Plugin_Gateway'); 
         add_action('woocommerce_api_' . strtolower(get_class($this)), array($this, 'handle_callback'));
}

public function handle_callback()
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
        error_log("hi callback");
        wp_die();
    }
}
```

I send this data to our gateway endpoint and return other url to redirect to bank

```php
$new_data = array(
            "platform" => "woocommerce",
            "paymentMethod" => "webpay",
            "x_account_id" => $this->token_service,
            "x_amount" => round($monto),
            "x_currency" => get_woocommerce_currency(),
            "x_customer_email" => $email,
            "x_customer_first_name" => $nombre_customer,
            "x_customer_last_name" => $apellido,
            "x_customer_phone" => $telefono,
            "x_description" => $cadenaProductos,
            "x_reference" => $order_id,
            "x_shop_country" => !empty($shop_country) ? $shop_country : 'CL',
            "x_shop_name" => $nombreSitio,
            "x_url_callback" => $this->notify_url,
            "x_url_cancel" => $this->notify_url,
            "x_url_complete" => $this->notify_url,
            "secret" => $_ENV['SECRET']
        );
```

My english is so bad, i hope you can help me, i am desperate look up by all internet

I followed the woocommerce documentation where I did the same with paypal but it didn't work and I also followed these links

https://jumpseller.com/support/external-payment-gateways/#response-parameters

https://developer.woo.com/docs/woocommerce-payment-gateway-api/#3-working-with-payment-gateway-callbacks-such-as-paypal-ipn-

https://developer.woo.com/docs/woocommerce-plugin-api-callbacks/

Comment: _"the url that appear is this: `http://localhost:8000/?wc-api=WC_Plugin_Gateway?x_account_id=...`"_ - with an actual question mark before the `x_account_id` parameter? That would be wrong in that place, the query string got already started with `?wc-api=`, so that second `?` would actually need to be a `&` instead. If(?) you specified `http://localhost:8000/?wc-api=WC_Plugin_Gateway` as your callback URL, then it looks like the gateway is not able to handle such URLs correctly, and you would likely have to use one without any query string parameters.

Comment: this part of the url `http://localhost:8000/?wc-api=WC_Plugin_Gateway` is generated by this variable `$this->notify_url = WC()->api_request_url('WC_Plugin_Gateway');` , should i change this?

Comment: those parameters are response by bank after pay or cancel pay, i change "?" with "&" and show me the same result

Comment: _"those parameters are response by bank after pay or cancel pay"_ - yes, I know that. But they need to get passed in a form that your system can actually "read", and with a malformed query string, that will not be the case. _"i change "?" with "&" and show me the same result"_ - what do you mean now, you changed it manually, with one such example URL, for testing?

Comment: if I change it inside the url hahaha, I thought that the callback function would show me something but no, according to what I have been told I must use the name of the class inside the hook, I don't think that the name does not follow a convention, at this point I don't know what to do anymore hahahaha

Comment: Not sure if https://developer.woo.com/docs/woocommerce-payment-gateway-api/#4-hooks-in-gateways has anything to do with this; try and add your hooks from outside the class.

Comment: I found another solution, for the moment I decided to capture those parameters separately on the checkout page, when the purchase is cancelled, and the thankyou page, when it is completed. I found some hooks called `woocommerce_thankyou ` and `woocommerce_checkout_order_review ` and so I can capture the get from the url. thank you very much anyway.